# How can I encrypt a drive with LUKS

Tags: disk-management, encryption

There are [tutorials](http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/howto-linux-hard-disk-encryption-with-luks-cryptsetup-command/) for setting up LUKS encryption on secondary drives in elementary OS, but is there a simpler way to do this with the existing graphical interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The easiest way is to install `gnome-disk-utility`

`sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility`

which you can run as `gnome-disks` in the Terminal or as "Disks" from the Applications menu. Then simply select the drive and in the "Type" selector, choose the LUKS encryption option. It will prompt for a password  (for the drive, not necessarily your login password) and you're good to go!

[image: LUKS]

You'll be asked on your next reboot how you'd like to unlock/mount the drive in the future. If you'd like to compare the options, look [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/108242/125239).

[image: Enter a passphrase to unlock the volume]

Comment: This is great! So easy. But how do I then mount this disk at boot? I've just added an external backup drive and formatted it LUKS+ext4 exactly as you show here except I chose to "Remember forever". It appears that the password is saved in seahorse (Passwords and Keys). How do I put `sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sdh1 My_Book` in fstab and make it use this saved password? Can this be done? pam_mount perhaps??

Comment: @JessetheWindWanderer Thanks! Most users, I imagine, will mount the disk by clicking its icon in the Files sidebar but mounting on login gets tricky, especially with LUKS and `fstab`. (Nautilus has built-in automount options that aren't active in Files—that method would be preferable as GNOME is already storing the passphrase.) I looked and didn't find much luck with scripting at login, so I think [`pam-mount`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pam_mount) is indeed your best bet